# python: pysal explanation of weight function

Tags: python, 2d, pysal

I have a 2D array of values and I'm trying to analyze spatial correlations. To calculate a 2D autocorrelation like [Moran's I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran%27s_I) in python, pysal provides an implementation. 
1) How do I transform my 2D data into a 1D array expected by pysal? 
2) How do I construct a weight array w that is based on distance (what does the input array of points mean in the [Kernel distance function](http://www.pysal.org/library/weights/user.html)?)?

Comment: That's probably too many questions, but if you get an answer to "how do I construct a weight array," please post it.

Answer (score 2):

1) The weights array should be flattened in the same way as you flatten the data array. The order doesn't matter, as long as the indices agree.

2) The input array can be spatial coordinates (e.g. *x* and *y*, or *lat* and *long*). By far the easiest are the indices of your original matrix (e.g. *1* to *n* times *1* to *m*).

In the end, your data will be a list with 3 elements: *x*, *y* and *value*. Your weights will be a list with 5 elements: *x_from*, *y_from*, *x_to*, *y_to* and *weight*.